# Does Autopilot have a concept of environments (dev/stage/prod) similar to Serverless?

Tags: twilio, runtime, environment, twilio-autopilot

I'm deploying our Twilio Functions (serverless) making use of --environments to isolate and promote from dev -> staging -> production but these need to be paired up with Autopilot for each environment. However, I don't see any corresponding concept in Autopilot.

Am I missing something in the Autopilot API?
Or is it recommended to create a complete separate Autopilot for each environment (e.g. Autopilot-Dev, Autopilot-Staging, Autopilot-Prod) with each one pointing to the appropriate Functions environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to create new Autopilot bots for each environment.

To make this easier, I recommend using the [Twilio Autopilot plugin for the Twilio CLI](https://github.com/dabblelab/twilio-cli-autopilot-plugin) which lets you import and export bots.